# OnTouchEvent stops firing when leaving parent, how change this behaviour?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

I want to implement drag-and-drop in an android application to switch a child view from one custom view to another custom view (of the same type).

My problem is that the OnTouchEvent stops firing when leaving the direct parent while draging (in my case the custom view is build like this: RelativeLayout -> (TextView, Button, LinearLayout -> (*LinearLayouts containing *ImageViews)). I want to show a list of images wrapped in more rows if the images doesn't fit in one row...)
In fact i want to drag one of those imageviews (parent is a linearlayout-row, where the parent is a linearlayout where parent is a relativelayout) to another custom view of the same type. (it just has to be droped over the other view and be added to the other list...) but it always  stops receiving the events when leaving its parent linear-layout.

Can you help me understand how the OnTouchEvent is handled when nested in different views? (already tried to add the OnTouchListener to every view and even the rootview of the activity)

Answer (score 0):

To continue to receive touch events outside of your View, call `getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` from onTouchEvent().